How can I enable secure boot after first boot?
I recently upgraded my system from Jammy to Noble Numbat however secure boot is turned off. I believe I skipped setting it up during the initial installation. I also installed new discrete tpm 2.0 chip on my computer and enabled it from bios.
chase@chase-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo mokutil --sb-state
[sudo] password for chase: 
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

The hardware security check report is attached below.
Device Security Report
======================

Report details
  Date generated:                                  2024-10-09 17:57:51
  fwupd version:                                   1.9.24

System details
  Hardware model:                                  ASUS System Product Name
  Processor:                                       AMD Ryzen 7 5700X 8-Core Processor
  OS:                                              Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
  Security level:                                  HSI:0! (v1.9.24)

HSI-1 Tests
  UEFI Bootservice Variables:                      Pass (Locked)
  TPM v2.0:                                        Pass (Found)
  BIOS Firmware Updates:                           Pass (Enabled)
  Fused Platform:                                ! Fail 
  UEFI Secure Boot:                              ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  TPM Platform Configuration:                      Pass (Valid)

HSI-2 Tests
  AMD Firmware Write Protection:                 ! Fail 
  TPM Reconstruction:                              Pass (Valid)
  IOMMU Protection:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Platform Debugging:                            ! Fail 

HSI-3 Tests
  Suspend To RAM:                                ! Fail (Enabled)
  Pre-boot DMA Protection:                       ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  AMD Firmware Replay Protection:                ! Fail 
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:             Pass (Supported)
  Suspend To Idle:                               ! Fail (Not Enabled)

HSI-4 Tests
  Encrypted RAM:                                 ! Fail 
  Supervisor Mode Access Prevention:               Pass (Enabled)
  AMD Secure Processor Rollback Protection:      ! Fail 

Runtime Tests
  Linux Kernel Verification:                     ! Fail (Tainted)
  Firmware Updater Verification:                   Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Swap:                                    ! Fail (Not Encrypted)
  Linux Kernel Lockdown:                         ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:             Pass (Supported)

Host security events

For information on the contents of this report, see https://fwupd.github.io/hsi.html


What is installed is set at installation time, if secure-boot isn't used at install time, the required secure-boot parts are not installed as they weren't required, where as if you installed with secure-boot enabled they will be installed. Triggering secure-boot is a matter of changing a uEFI(BIOS) Settings only; and if your system was setup for secure uEFI at install it'll boot.  The release-upgrade won't change this, its part of install setup.

Why do you think you would need secure boot? It is really not necessary to securely run Ubuntu. Someone else with physical access can destroy your system anyway

I understand that secure boot doesn't really have much to do with the upgrade but it worked on jammy jellyfish and isn't now. I had to to a clean install of noble to get it to work and am in the process of moving everything over. My system is detecting the tpm chip I'm just unsure how to set it up after the initial installation. I don't want to do another clean install just for secure boot. Also, I'm just trying t see if I can get secure boot working simply for the sake of it.

Can you append to your question the result of 'mokutil --list-new'

'mokutil --list new' returns nothing. Would using the mokutil --enable-validation command work?

From what i could find the MOK key is automatically generated by ubuntu during a fresh install. Since I opted out of setting it up then, what can i do?https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot

I think I figured it out myself. In order to enable it I had to go into my bios settings and enable secure boot as Windows compliant UEFI secure boot for Noble to be satisfied with it. The updated device security report it attached below. Apparently, on Noble Numbat they made secure boot Windows compliant and that needs to be reflected in your bios settings.
Device Security Report
======================

Report details
  Date generated:                                  2024-10-10 10:38:25
  fwupd version:                                   1.9.24

System details
  Hardware model:                                  ASUS System Product Name
  Processor:                                       AMD Ryzen 7 5700X 8-Core Processor
  OS:                                              Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
  Security level:                                  HSI:0! (v1.9.24)

HSI-1 Tests
  UEFI Platform Key:                               Pass (Valid)
  UEFI Bootservice Variables:                      Pass (Locked)
  TPM v2.0:                                        Pass (Found)
  BIOS Firmware Updates:                           Pass (Enabled)
  UEFI Secure Boot:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Fused Platform:                                ! Fail 
  TPM Platform Configuration:                      Pass (Valid)

HSI-2 Tests
  AMD Firmware Write Protection:                 ! Fail 
  TPM Reconstruction:                              Pass (Valid)
  IOMMU Protection:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Platform Debugging:                            ! Fail 

HSI-3 Tests
  Suspend To RAM:                                ! Fail (Enabled)
  Pre-boot DMA Protection:                       ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  AMD Firmware Replay Protection:                ! Fail 
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:             Pass (Supported)
  Suspend To Idle:                               ! Fail (Not Enabled)

HSI-4 Tests
  Encrypted RAM:                                 ! Fail 
  Supervisor Mode Access Prevention:               Pass (Enabled)
  AMD Secure Processor Rollback Protection:      ! Fail 

Runtime Tests
  Linux Kernel Verification:                     ! Fail (Tainted)
  Firmware Updater Verification:                   Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Swap:                                    ! Fail (Not Encrypted)
  Linux Kernel Lockdown:                           Pass (Enabled)
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:             Pass (Supported)

Host security events
  2024-10-10 10:32:27   Linux Kernel Lockdown        Pass (Not Enabled → Enabled)
  2024-10-10 10:32:27   UEFI Secure Boot             Pass (Not Enabled → Enabled)

For information on the contents of this report, see https://fwupd.github.io/hsi.html

The output of mokutil --sb-state is
chase@chase-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled


Now I just need to find out what the failed portions of the device security report are.
